# Notation used in Tensor analysis

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

I have come across the following notations for matrices in relativity: $X_{\nu}{}^{\mu}$ and $X^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$. How are these things related?

Answer (score 2):

Usually coordinates of points or vectors in $d$ dimensions are denoted by $x^{\mu}$ with $\mu=1,\ldots,d$. A metric would be given by a symmetric matrix $g_{\mu\nu}$
with lower indices. You then also have $g^{\mu \nu}$ given by the $\mu,\nu$ entry of the inverse matrix $g^{-1}$.
A linear map would be written ${X^{\mu}}_{\nu}$ and from the vector $x^{\mu}$ it would produce the vector $y^{\mu}={X^{\mu}}_{\nu}x^{\nu}:=\sum_{\nu}{X^{\mu}}_{\nu}x^{\nu}$. Finally, you can use $g$ or $g^{-1}$ to raise or lower indices. So your ${X_{\nu}}^{\mu}$ is actually defined by
${X_{\nu}}^{\mu}=g_{\nu\alpha}g^{\mu\beta}{X^{\alpha}}_{\beta}$ with summation over $\alpha$ and $\beta$ understood. In sum, your two objects are two different $d\times d$ matrices that are related by multiplication on the left and right by $g$ or $g^{-1}$.